# Getting user input upon pressing a space

Tags: c++, input

I am trying to tackle this condition where the user has to input a number n. and then entering n numbers after it on the same line. Therefore my program needs to know this number n before the user continues to input so that the programs knows how large of a dynamic array it needs to save these numbers inputted after n.  (It is crucial that all of this happens on one line).

I tried the following but it doesn't seem to work.

```
int r; 
cin >> r;

//CL is a member function of a certain class
CL.R = r;
CL.create(r); //this is a member function creates the needed dynamic arrays E and F used bellow 

int u, v;
for (int j = 0; j < r; j++)
{
   cin >> u >> v;
   CL.E[j] = u;
   CL.F[j] = v;
}
```

Comment: You should probably use `std::vector`, but otherwise this parsing solution works fine for me.  What exactly isn't working?

Comment: Why do you want the user to separate number with a space instead of an enter? My keyboard includes an `Enter` key in the numeric keypad.

Answer (score 2):

You can do that as usual on a single line:

```
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  int *array;
  string line;
  getline(cin,line); //read the entire line
  int size;
  istringstream iss(line);
  if (!(iss >> size))
  {
    //error, user did not input a proper size
  }
  else
  {
    //be sure to check that size > 0
    array = new int[size];
    for (int count = 0 ; count < size ; count++)
    {
      //we put each input in the array
      if (!(iss >> array[count]))
      {
        //this input was not an integer, we reset the stream to a good state and ignore the input
        iss.clear();
        iss.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(),' ');
      }
    }
    cout << "Array contains:" << endl;
    for (int i = 0 ; i < size ; i++)
    {
      cout << array[i] << ' ' << flush;
    }
    delete[] (array);
  }
}
```

And here is the [demonstration](http://ideone.com/jkm4em), you can see that the input is one line `6 1 2 3 4 5 6`.

Once again, I did **not** check everything, so take care of that the way you need.

Edit: added reset of the stream after a bad read.

Comment: I see `using namespace std` but I can't see `vector<int>` ;)

Comment: If OP wants a solution with `vectors` I'd be happy to provide one, but I think this looks like an exercise to understand dynamic allocation, so it would not be allowed.